# How can I print a views exposed form into a custom block?

Tags: views, blocks

I have a page view with exposed filters and would like to print said filters into a custom block in order to add extra html markup above the actual form.  This block will be used on other pages using Context.

I know I can create a block by setting 'exposed filters in block' to yes, however that's not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hours and hours of searching and nothing was working.  Several minutes after posting this question, I figured it out.  The following code can be used in template files or blocks.

```
<?php
  $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', '-exp-VIEW_NAME-DISPLAY_NAME');
  print render($block['content']);
?>
```

Comment: There are so many ways to manage this with `code`. Nice finding though.

Comment: Yeah, there were tons of other very complex solutions out there!  This one is short and simple.  Granted I am sure there are use cases for the other solutions.

Comment: On another note, thanks for coming back to tell people your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Its simple take a look at the screenshot. [image]

Comment: I understand thats one way to do it, but that wasn't the solution I was looking for.  I needed to be able to add HTML markup above the actual form.  Thanks though.

Comment: @filmoreha Well. A simple tweak is to make a module with custom markup and handle it same way like this form via contextual filters or something.. I am also looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7:

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$display_id = 'page'; // Display: page/block
$view->set_display($display_id);
$view->init_handlers();
$form_state = array(
    'view' => $view,
    'display' => $view->display_handler->display,
    'exposed_form_plugin' => $view->display_handler->get_plugin('exposed_form'),
    'method' => 'get',
    'rerender' => TRUE,
    'no_redirect' => TRUE,
    'always_process' => TRUE, // This is important for handle the form status.
);
$form = drupal_build_form('views_exposed_form', $form_state);
print drupal_render($form);
```

'always_process' is main form state argument for handle the exposed filter form status.

From https://www.drupal.org/node/2854114